# JQuery Animation with ScrollTop

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, scroll, scrolltop

Hello Stackoverflow people!

I am having some trouble in JavaScript since I've been experiementing a little with different things something I've had a lot of trouble with is the following:

```
$(document).scroll(function () {
    $('.header').toggleClass('scrolled', $(this).scrollTop() > 1);
});
```

This works fine, but I want to add an "animation" to it where it fades in when I scroll down on my page, and fades out when I scroll to the top of my page.
The class "Scrolled" is what I want to fade in and out.

Somebody that might be able to help me with this?

Comment: Try adding css `.Scrolled{ transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out }`

Comment: @azs06 Thanks xD That worked, had to add it to the .header class aswell tho, but it works.